# Simple drag and drop with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, draggable

Here is some basic drag and drop JS from W3Schools

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

<html>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</html>
```

I would like to make this work with my angular app but having trouble wrapping my mind around "the angular way" of going about this.

I know I can include the functions as part of the scope, but are there ng-drop and ng-drag events with which to bind them??

Do I need to write a custom directive??

Comment: Look into dragula.

Comment: I checked out dracula but I'd really like to  implement this manually for learning purposes

Comment: You could always take a look at the dragula or angular-dnd source code for inspiration.

Comment: yes, I have done this of course but its fairly complicated, and while reverse engineering something is a great way to learn, I was hoping for a very simple proof of concept just to get an idea of how this applies in angular